# Making a data structure available to all instances of a class?

Tags: matlab, oop, data-structures, static-variables

I have a node data structure that represents nodes in a binary tree. I have some data that is relevant to the entire tree and rather than storing copies of it in each node, I just store indices in nodes that I use to access this global data. So my `Node` class has a constant property `TreeData` that contains the data I want available to all nodes:

```
classdef Node

    properties (Constant)
        treeData = TreeData
    end

    ...
    ...
end
```

with TreeData being defined as

```
classdef TreeData < handle
    properties
        s
        w
    end
end
```

This works fine, however its a nuisance having an entire extra class (`TreeData`) just to define two variables that should be accessible to all the nodes. So is there a better way of doing this? In another language I would just declare a static variable in the `Node` class to hold this data but in MATLAB it seems like you need getters and setters for static variables, which would end up leading to even more code having to be written than this `TreeData` class.

I don't just want something that works, I already have that, I'm looking for the most efficient/best-practice way to make a data structure available to all instances of a class in MATLAB.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40741595/3372061) shows a demonstration of "static variables" in MATLAB using `persistent` variables (see `function out = currentClass(input)` in the first snippet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way might be to just define a global variable. If you use a long enough name, there's a good chance you will never have a naming conflict. Simple, yes. Best practice, no.

Matlab [does have static-like variables](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/persistent.html), but they use the keyword `persistent`. They are local to the function where they are declared, but their values persist in memory between calls to the function. It's similar to how some other languages allow you to create static local variables for a function.

It's hard to say what the best solution is for your situation without knowing how you are using this variable. If the variable is a counter, you could create an `adjustCounter` function that accepts an amount to adjust the counter and returns the new value. Getting the counter value is simply a matter of telling it to adjust by 0.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450204/how-to-obtain-static-member-variables-in-matlab-classes) is another similar question with several different suggested solutions.