# How to get the calling subclass' name in a superclass' static function?

Tags: matlab, oop, inheritance, static-methods, introspection

Suppose we have
Check.m:

```
classdef Check < handle
methods (Static)
    function doStuff()
        if isCalledFromAssertSubclass
            % do this stuff only if called as Assert.doStuff(), not if called as Check.doStuff()
        end
        % do other stuff
    end
end
end
```

and Assert.m:

```
classdef Assert < Check
    % nop
end
```

As written in the comment, I would like to have that `Check.doStuff()` executes only the "do other stuff" line and that `Assert.doStuff()` executes the `if isCalledFromAssertSubclass` block as well.

I want to use static methods, so that I don't neet to create an Assert object whenever I need an assert. Using a global assert object is also very ugly and needs a `global assert` line in each function I want to use an assert. Likewise for checks.

So there are two problems:

1. Since these are static classes, there is no chance of using `class(obj)` or any other non-static class property or function.
2. `dbstack` is not inheritance aware and always returns `Check` as calling class, also for `Assert.doStuff`.

I did find a working solution, which uses a combination of `dbstack` and `dbtype` to read the line where the call came from, i.e. the line where it says `Assert.doStuff()`. However it involves two debug functions which probably should not be used in productive code and more importent, dbtype is very slow (in my case, 30 our of 70 seconds!).

I could use a package instead (directory `+Check` with function files in there) and create a symlink `+Assert -> +Check`. Then I could check the file name, but that's a) not portable, b) quite ugly and c) also somewhat slow (I suppose).

Is there any faster method for this?

Comment: The requirement of this being a static method makes this a lot harder... you could have a simple overload if it wasn't

Comment: I think this is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31269260/call-subclass-static-method-from-inside-superclass-static-method

Comment: Yes but that's the whole point. Having Asserts needs to be as non-invasive as possible. Creating an object befor being able to use asserts is too clumsy.
And if I human-compiled the answer to the linked question correctly, it's not really a duplicate. If I need to write a small function in the subclass for each function in the superclass, I could just write Check.duStuff() (see answer to Chris Luengos answer). Or did I misread it?

Comment: It seems there is no built-in meethod for this. See Cris Lunego's answer for a workaround which works in probably most cases (including mine).

Comment: if Cris solved your question then please mark their answer as accepted

Comment: Ok, if this is the way to go here, I happily follow :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not overload the static method for `Assert`, and have it call the parent's method when it's done? This is the normal way of using inheritance: you don't want the parent, `Check`, to know anything about its child, `Assert`.

This is what it would look like:

```matlab
classdef Assert < Check
methods (Static)
    function doStuff()
        % do some stuff
        Check.doStuff()
    end
end
end
```

As [@Wolfie suggests in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58541969/how-to-get-the-calling-subclass-name-in-a-superclass-static-function/58545614?noredirect=1#comment103412602_58545614), the above works as long as `Check.doStuff` is not sealed. A sealed method cannot be overloaded. See the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/static-methods.html#bu5tm4_).

Comment: To make this hold water, I'd include this quote from the [docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/static-methods.html) `Subclasses can redefine static methods unless the method's Sealed attribute is also set to true in the superclass` - I had overcomplicated this problem by assuming the opposite, looks like your solution should work.

Comment: @Wolfie: thanks for that detail, I've included it in the answer.

Comment: Yes, this is what I ended up writing. I agree that it's probably the cleanest solution. 
However, the purpose was to not have to maintain two functions for each assert/check routine (I have 48 at the moment...).
With the slow dbtype solution, I just had to write one function for each check.

Comment: @Tasnad: Two smaller functions instead of one larger one, and no repeated code.

Comment: Well, it was one line "Check.handleAssert()" in each check function, but I still agree that it's cleaner this way. And this way, I could separate the error throwing functionality from the check function, which is even nicer.
However, this still does not answer the original question :) It seems that there is no proper built-in way to determine the class name...

Comment: @Tasnad if the solution you ended up with differs significantly from what's suggested here, please post your own answer. Otherwise, it would be great if you could [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) to indicate that your problem was solved.

Comment: I don't think the original question it is solved. Cris Luengo's idea is what I am using anyways now, but I'm still interested how one could solve this problem (maybe there is some Java trickery or so?). However, I added a comment that his answer is a good workaround.